# i18next force to refetch from backend

Tags: reactjs, react-native, internationalization

I am running a

```
import { default as i18n } from 'i18next'
import ChainedBackend from 'i18next-chained-backend'
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend'
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'


i18n.use(initReactI18next).use(ChainedBackend).init(
    backend: {
      backends: [HttpApi, resourcesToBackend(bundledResources)],
      backendOptions: [
        {
          loadPath: (languages: string[], namespaces: string[]) => {
            const [lng] = languages
            const [ns] = namespaces

            return `${API_S3}locales/${lng}/${ns}.json`
          },
        },
        {
          /* options for local files */
        },
      ],
    },)
```

With options such as backend (to fetch from an s3 server every time the app launch).

Is it possible to run this fetch again to the s3 server periodically or in a function (by running i18n.init again for example) ?

Answer (score 0):

i18next-http-backend has a reloadInterval option: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend#backend-options

[image]

Comment: It's not available with `i18next-chained-backend`, backend options are only `backends` and `backendOptions`

Comment: for sure all backend options can be passed also via chained-backend

Comment: no, I mean reloadInterval is not available in options.

Comment: for sure it is: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend/blob/master/index.d.ts#L82

Comment: it does not work